# Resetting radio buttons when changing dropdown

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form comprising of a dropdown menu (where u can select a parameter to plot in a graph) and two radio buttons (to decide whether or not the graph is autoscaled. If not, there is a text box where you can define the scale). When I change the parameter in the dropdown, the graph is automatically redrawn with the new parameter.

However I want the radio buttons to be reset, so if I chose a manual scale, and I change my parameter, it changes back to autoscale. Is this possible?
Here is part of my form code:

```
<select id="Graf1" onchange="makeChoice5();updateSelect(this,'Graf2');this.form.submit();" name="graf1">
    <option value="other">---------- Kies ---------- </option>
    <option value="1">Temperatuur</option>
    <option value="2">Relatieve vochtigheid</option>
    <option value="3">Straling</option>
    <option value="4">Dendrometer 1</option>
    <option value="5">Dendrometer 2</option>
    </select>
    </br>
    <input type="radio" name="schaal" value="1" checked="checked" onclick="makeChoice();">Automatische schaal </br>
    <input type="radio" name="schaal" value="other" onclick="makeChoice();">Handmatig
    <input type="text" name="schaalmin" size="6" value="---Min---" onclick="clickclear(this, '---Min---')" onkeydown="return ( event.ctrlKey || event.altKey 
        || (47<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<58 && event.shiftKey==false) 
        || (95<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<106) || (event.keyCode==8) 
        || (event.keyCode==9) || (event.keyCode>34 && event.keyCode<40) 
        || (event.keyCode==46)
        || (event.keyCode==110) )">
    <input type="text" name="schaalmax" size="6" value="---Max---" onclick="clickclear(this, '---Max---')"  onkeydown="return ( event.ctrlKey || event.altKey
        || (47<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<58 && event.shiftKey==false) 
        || (95<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<106) || (event.keyCode==8) 
        || (event.keyCode==9) || (event.keyCode>34 && event.keyCode<40) 
        || (event.keyCode==46)
        || (event.keyCode==110) )">
```

Comment: You really should think about moving your event handlers into javscript. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_and_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I just used this small easy function, which is called on changing the dropdown.. This way when I change the parameter, the right radiobutton is selected (in stead of trying to unselect the other ones):

```
function clearRadios() {
    document.form1.schaal[0].checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons of the same name are an array, so you have to loop through each one and clear them (unless you're using jQuery where it is easy to determine which one is selected and clear it directly).

Clearing them would work something like this:

```
var r = document.forms[0].schaal
for(var x=0;x<r.length;x++) {
      document.forms[0].schaal[x].checked = false
}
```